# How to hang a mosquito net from a ceiling without causing damage?

Tags: ceiling

We have one of those hoop-style mosquito net that hangs off a single hook. When we first put it up, we hung the net with a small brass hook--the kind that you just screw into the ceiling with no wall anchor for lightweight stuff. Maybe not ideal, but we already had it on hand and it seemed to work ok.

Until...our son either jumped or sat on the net or rolled on it and the whole hook fell out of the ceiling with the net. We could just replace the hook with a larger hook that has a wall anchor, but I'm a bit concerned about whether if he rolls, yanks, or jumps on the net, it's going to either rip a bigger hole in the ceiling and/or rip the net in half. Is there a way we could attach the net so it would safely detach from the ceiling if it is yanked sufficient tension that won't result in it falling down every couple days?

Comment: @isherwood I'm confused how this is a furniture question other than a bed being mentioned. I'm also wondering why furniture questions are off topic.

Comment: It probably should've just asked how to mount to a _ceiling_. I apologize if I misread. I've reversed my vote. As to the rules of the site, that was before my time and above my pay grade. See the [help] for some insight.

Comment: @isherwood I was mostly asking, because furniture is not listed on [the page describing off-topic subjects](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Some conversations that may help: https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=furniture

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps velcro would work for you.

You can buy adhesive-backed velcro strips or squares.  Use the adhesive to stick the velcro to the ceiling, and to the net.

If the adhesive doesn't hold onto the net, sew some velcro to the net with a little thread.

If the adhesive doesn't hold onto the ceiling, hang a short loop of velcro from a better ceiling hook.

Answer (score 2):

Use coaxial cable clips.  Don't screw the flap side in.  Also the part that you screw in, leave a small gap so that you can tuck a little of the flap side in.

I have two cable lines in my basement laundry room that I switch (don't ask).  It holds the cable great which is heavier than a mosquito net and with a good tug my cable is on the ground.  Of course this will work better if you screw into wood and if you aren't then you want to use some sort of anchor.  You can play with the "tug rate" needed for collapse by how much you tuck in and how tight it is.  Really with a mosquito net this could be very loose.  And the small screw holes can be easily concealed after.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about installing wall anchors with relatively large flathead screws and then using magnetic hooks? Perhaps [something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01G96LB6U), although you might be able to go with something even lighter duty depending on the weight of your net. That should have no problem staying up since mosquito nets are so light but also pull down easily without damage.

Answer (score -1):

Use an eyescrew with a good strong hold, but then add a hitch pin clip.

[image: hitch pin clip]

You can put the pin's eye on the net with the release part clinging to the eyescrew. Alternatively, you can put the pin's eye on the eyescrew with the release part clinging to the net. The beefier the hitch pin clip, the larger the tension required.

Comment: Care to explain how one should go about using the cotter pin? While _you_ can imagine a couple of feasible configurations, unfortunately, _my_ imagination just isn't good enough today.

Comment: When you remove a cotter pin, you have to pull on it to overcome its holding strength. You can put the pin's eye on the net with the release part clinging to the eyescrew. Alternatively, you can put the pin's eye on the eyescrew with the release part clinging to the net.

Comment: Please expand your answer from comments

Comment: Still doesn't help _me_ very much. A drawing would probably help. After all, a [cotter pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotter_%28pin%29) is usually designed to hold something _tightly_ in place. A [split pin (or R-clip)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_pin) gives a somewhat loose connection. Both are designed to _prevent_ something from coming apart. Maybe we're using the same term for something completely different...

Comment: @FreeMan, sorry. Upon reflection, I've never known the formal name of the doodad that I had in mind.

Comment: Hence my suggestion for drawings, pictures, whatever...